# Problema com programa em PHP

Tags: php

Estou precisando de ajuda com um exercício em php que estou fazendo. Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendario.php on line 5

Recebe a mesma mensagem de erro para as linhas de 5 à 10 do código. Essas linhas referem-se a impressão em tela dos valores que deveria estar em um vetor. Pelo mensagem de erro, parece que o vetor não recebeu os valores corretos.

Segue código na integra:

```
<?php 
    function linha($semana){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>{$semana[0]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[1]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[2]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[3]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[4]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[5]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[6]}</td>           
             </tr>";
    }

    function calendario(){
        $dia=1;
        $semana=array();
        while($dia<=31){
            array_push($semana, $dia);
            if(count($semana)==7);{
                linha($semana);
                $semana=array();
            }
            $dia++;
        }
    }

?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Dom</th>
        <th>Seg</th>
        <th>Ter</th>
        <th>Qua</th>
        <th>Qui</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Sáb</th>
    </tr>
    <?php calendario();?>

</table>
```

Comment: Que que você quer fazer ?

Comment: Esse programa vai imprimir um calendário usando uma tabela em html. O meu problema na verdade está sendo a mensagem de erro. Não consegui descobrir o porque está dando o erro. Resolvendo o problema da mensagem de erro acredito que eu consiga terminar o programa tranquilamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro é só um ponto e vírgula indevido.

```
<?php 
    function linha($semana){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>{$semana[0]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[1]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[2]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[3]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[4]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[5]}</td>
                <td>{$semana[6]}</td>           
             </tr>";
    }

    function calendario(){
        $dia=1;
        $semana=array();
        while($dia<=31){
            array_push($semana, $dia);
            if(count($semana)==7){ // REMOVI O PONTO E VIRGULA DAQUI
                linha($semana);
                $semana=array();
            }
            $dia++;
        }
    }

?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Dom</th>
        <th>Seg</th>
        <th>Ter</th>
        <th>Qua</th>
        <th>Qui</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Sáb</th>
    </tr>
    <?php calendario();?>

</table>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Allan. Era isso mesmo.